# Update of primary key would cause duplicate entries in foreign table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables described by the following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00d66e). My application needs to insert new records in `tblA` in between two already existing records. For example, if tblA has 6 records with `AID` ranging from 0 to 5 and I want to insert a new record with `AID` being 4, I increment the `AID` of tuple 4 and tuple 5 by one and then insert the new record. Thus, I use the following prepared statement to increment the value of the column `AID` of the tuples of both `tblA` and `tblB` (via cascading) by one:

```
update tblA set AID = (AID + 1) where AID >= ? order by AID desc;
```

On my test Installation the above Statement works great. However, on our production system we get the following error message in some, but not all cases:

```
Foreign key constraint for table 'tblA', record '4' would lead to a duplicate entry in table 'tblB'
```

Now, it is unclear to me what exactly causes the problem and how to solve the issue.

I appreciate any tips. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About tblB**

This

```
create table if not exists tblB(
  BID integer not null, 
  AID integer not null, 
  constraint fkB_A foreign key(AID) references tblA(AID), 
  primary key(AID, BID)
);
```

should probably be

```
create table if not exists tblB(
  BID integer not null, 
  AID integer not null, 
  constraint fkB_A foreign key(AID) references tblA(AID)
    on update cascade, 
  -- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  primary key(AID, BID)
);
```

Surrogate ID numbers in the relational model of data and in SQL databases are meaningless. Unless you know more than you've included in your question, AID and BID are meaningless. In a properly designed database, there's never a need to insert a row *between* two other rows *based solely on their surrogate ID numbers*.

If your real-world requirement is simply to insert a timestamp between "2015-12-01 23:07:00" and "2015-12-04 14:58:00", you don't need the ID number 4 to do that.

```
-- Use single quotes around timestamps.
insert into tblA values (-42, '2015-12-03 00:00:00');
select * from tblA order by RecordDate;
```

```
AID       RecordDate
--
  0       2015-11-07 16:55:00
  1       2015-11-08 22:16:00
  2       2015-11-10 14:26:00
  3       2015-12-01 23:07:00
-42       2015-12-03 00:00:00
  5       2015-12-04 14:58:00
  6       2015-12-13 10:07:00
```

**About tblA**

This

```
create table if not exists tblA(
  AID integer not null, 
  RecordDate varchar(25), 
  constraint pkA primary key(AID)
);
```

should probably be

```
create table if not exists tblA(
  AID integer not null, 
  RecordDate varchar(25) not null, 
  --                     ^^^^^^^^
  constraint pkA primary key(AID)
);
```

Without that `not null`, you can insert data like this.

```
AID  RecordDate
--
17   Null
18   Null
19   Null
```

Since surrogate ID numbers are meaningless, these rows are all essentially both identical and identically useless.

**About the update statement**

```
update tblA 
set AID = (AID + 1) 
where AID >= 4 
order by AID desc;
```

Standard SQL doesn't permit `order by` in this position in update statement. [MySQL documents this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) as

> If the ORDER BY clause is specified, the rows are updated in the order
>   that is specified.

The relational model and SQL are set-oriented. Updates are supposed to happen "all at once". IMHO, you'd be better off learning standard SQL and using a dbms that better supports standard SQL. (PostgreSQL springs to mind.) But adding `on update cascade` to tblB (above) will let your update statement succeed in MySQL.

```
update tblA 
set AID = (AID + 1) 
where AID >= 4 order by AID desc;
```

Comment: Thank's a lot. I am simply going to append the new curves to the end of the table and try to order them by the `RecordDate` in my select statement.

Answer (score 0):

adding `on update cascade` might solve your problem

```
create table if not exists tblB(
       BID integer not null, 
       AID integer not null, 
       constraint fkB_A foreign key(AID) 
             references tblA(AID)
             on update cascade, 
             primary key(AID, BID));
```